# How to run Wiki on the same host as Wordpress and not get 404 errors when browsing to Wiki?

Tags: urls

If I have Wordpress in a virtual host and deploy Mediawiki to it, then when I browse to the deployed path, for example to `www.mysite.com/wiki`, then I get 404 even if I specify `index.php` or any other existing script as target. Do I have to create a separate virtual host for Wiki and link to it, for it to work?

Comment: Use a subdomain for the mediawiki install is the easy answer. eg. wiki.mysite.com. You may want to start over, get a subdomain setup, then run the installer using the subdomain address, so the install makes appropriate references to the correct address.

Comment: You'll need to configure Apache to know that /wiki doesn't belong to WordPress, either in a .conf file or the WordPress .htaccess. I don't know what the best way to do this is though: probably a new set of rewrite rules in the <Location> or <Directory> block for the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the deployed path and set it to a new one then try.
Also, you can add it to a subdomain like app.mysite.com.

Comment: The deployed path of mediawiki or WordPress?